# YA short story about a child who is menaced by squishy hearts

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult

I have very spotty recollections of this story, but I think I read it in a collection or anthology of YA horror.

The story is about a child, who is either adopted or fostered, who moves into a new house where he encounters giant squishy hearts at night that envelop him and smother him. I can't remember if this is the entire premise of the story or just one scene that has stuck out to me.